# How to do global exception handler in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have search exception handler in postgres it says to add

```
DECLARE
  text_var1 text;
  text_var2 text;
  text_var3 text;
BEGIN
  -- some processing which might cause an exception
  ...
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS text_var1 = MESSAGE_TEXT,
                          text_var2 = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
                          text_var3 = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;
-- call a function which log all this variable perform log_function (text_var1 ,text_var2 , text_var3 );
END;
```

If I do that for every function is this efficient?

Any performance lack by this approach?

Can't we have a global exception handler for all functions? In this approach I have added the exception handler for every function.

Then save them in variable and save log for that. Can we have any global error handler for that?

**Edit**

I have to log all exception coming in postgres into a table . I am following this step.

1) write GET STACKED block in all function (if i have 20 function then i write this block in all function)

2)Than log then in table.

What i want is there should be mechanism for global exception handler in postgres , So that i have to not write GET STACKED EXCEPTION block in postgres for all function

Comment: yes - you can log errors to log and use csv log format to import it to a table - I think this is the meant way to catch all exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `EXCEPTION` clause in a PL/pgSQL block has a negative performance impact; see the “tip” in [the documentation of error trapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

There is no way to automatically handle all top-level exceptions in a PL/pgSQL function.

My recommendation is that you don't log errors in database functions, but from the application. For one, when your transaction rolls back, the log will be gone.

Comment: that code is sample how the exception handled currently. For current process i have to write this block in all function . can we do that by any global handler in postgres?

Comment: I have added more info and use case in edit section.